# LINQ - Static columns transposition into aggregate rows values

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

Currently I have table that looks like below:

```
Id    StockCompanyId    StockIndexId    FilterDatePeriodId    Q0     Q1     Q2     Q3     Q4     Q5     Q6     Q7     Q8     Q9     Q10     Q11     Q12     Q13     Q14     Q15     Q16     Q17     Q18     Q19     Q20
6301  4                 1               NULL                  NULL   NULL   NULL   0.14   0.14   0.14   0.14   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL    0.05    0.05    0.05    0.05    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
6553  1                 1               NULL                  NULL   NULL   NULL   0.53   0.53   0.53   0.53   0.58   0.58   0.58   0.58    0.55    0.55    0.55    0.55    0.50    0.50    0.50    0.50    0.43    0.43
6805  2                 1               NULL                  NULL   NULL   NULL   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.05   0.05   0.05   0.05    0.08    0.08    0.08    0.08    0.06    0.06    0.06    0.06    0.07    0.07
7057  3                 1               NULL                  NULL   NULL   NULL   0.11   0.11   0.11   0.11   0.13   0.13   0.13   0.13    0.17    0.17    0.17    0.17    0.17    0.17    0.17    0.17    0.17    0.17
7309  5                 1               NULL                  NULL   NULL   NULL   0.16   0.16   0.16   0.16  -0.16  -0.16  -0.16  -0.16    0.19    0.19    0.19    0.19   -0.34   -0.34   -0.34   -0.34    0.00    0.00
```

Columns are static by design, we always keep 20Q of financial data no more, and when new quarter comes we move all data from left to right and put new value into Q0

What I currently need is transposed version of above with aggregated function.

> For selected group of Companies (collection of StockCompanyId), and provided Stock Index (StockIndexId) **calculate average value by each quarter and present it from the newest quarter to the latest quarter**.

So the final result should look like:

```
Quarter    Aggregated Value
0          0.53    <-- Average(values for all matched companies and provided stock index)
1          0.71
2          0.81
3          ...
4          ...
5          ...
6          ...
7          ...
8          ...
9          ...
10         ...
11         ...
12         ...
13         ...
14         ...
15         ...
16         ...
17         ...
18         ...
19         ...
20         ...
```

And sent this data as list of DTO model:

```
public class DTO
{
    public string Quarter {get; set;}
    public decimal AggregatedValue {get; set;}
}

List<DTO> ResponseValues
```

Can any one help me build LINQ query that will achieve this requirement?

Comment: Your table design is highly non-standard and doesn't lend itself well to LINQ-style queries... I don't see any way to do less than 20 queries unless you use dynamic LINQ.

Comment: Yes I know that they are non-standard, this is specific financial design. I would not post it here if it would be trivial. I believe that it can be "somehow" achieved.

Answer (score 0):

It's a kludge, but this should work:

```
var matches = (
  from entry in table
  where entry.StockIndexId == StockIndexId
  where Companies.Contains(entry.StockCompanyId)
  select entry).ToList();

var ResponseValues = new List<DTO>();

ResponseValues.Add(new DTO {
  Quarter = 0,
  AggregatedValue = matches.Sum(
    match => match.Q0 ?? 0
  ) / matches.Length
});
ResponseValues.Add(new DTO {
  Quarter = 1,
  AggregatedValue = matches.Sum(
    match => match.Q1 ?? 0
  ) / matches.Length
});
... snip ...
ResponseValues.Add(new DTO {
  Quarter = 20,
  AggregatedValue = matches.Sum(
    match => match.Q20 ?? 0
  ) / matches.Length
});
```